# Efficient locking for a conditional insert inside a larger transaction

Tags: locking, transaction, sql-server-2019

I have a script I'm using to merge incoming data into a table that includes a conditional insert to capture some related data.

For example, where `[#Records]` contains the incoming data:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [Batch] (Id)
SELECT DISTINCT BatchId
FROM [#Records]
WHERE BatchId NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM [Batch])

-- Do a MERGE here with lots of records that might take a while

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

The problem with this insert is that it may fail if run concurrently (due to a primary key constraint on `[Batch]`).

The advice I found was that I should be using `UPDLOCK` and `HOLDLOCK` to lock the `[Batch]` table for this insert:

```
INSERT INTO [Batch] (Id)
SELECT DISTINCT BatchId
FROM [#Records]
WHERE Id NOT IN (SELECT Id FROM [Batch] WITH (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK))
```

It also suggested that I wrap that insert in its own transaction, however, irrespective of whether I use a "nested" transaction here or not, my understanding is that the lock on `[Batch]` will be held until the end of the "outer" transaction. Is this correct?

As the other statements in the transaction may take a while I'd like to avoid the `[Batch]` table being locked until the end.

What is the most efficient way to do this?